# Remove html links with jQuery

Tags: jquery, replace, hyperlink

I have a jQuery string:

```
<p>
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod</h1>
  tempor invidunt ut labore et
  <a target="_blank" class="marked user-link" href="/user/fc07254b-c063-47e1-a434-0da87b62d105">
    <img class="avatar-big-shadow" src="/avatars/fc07254b-c063-47e1-a434-0da87b62d105.png" alt="Hitzk0pf" />
    <span>Hitzk0pf</span>
  </a>
  lore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
  At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  <a target="_blank" class="marked user-link" href="/user/a9641490-56e7-41c8-a4d7-3bb0b96d5d8a">
    <img class="avatar-big-shadow" src="/avatars/a9641490-56e7-41c8-a4d7-3bb0b96d5d8a.png" alt="Hitzk0pf"/ >
    <span>Hawked</span>
  </a>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
  <a target="_blank" class="marked user-link" href="/user/fc07254b-c063-47e1-a434-0da87b62d105">
    <img class="avatar-big-shadow" src="/avatars/fc07254b-c063-47e1-a434-0da87b62d105.png" alt="Hitzk0pf">
    <span>Hitzk0pf</span>
  </a>
  At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
```

Above you can see, that there are many `<a>` tags in my string. In the `<a>` tags there are `img` and `span` tags.

**The output should look like this:**

```
<p>
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod</h1>
  tempor invidunt ut labore et Hitzk0pf lore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
  At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  Hawked Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
  Hitzk0pf At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
```

As you can see, I want to replace the `<a>` tag with the content of the `span` tag.

Normally I would use this:

```
$('.marked').find('span').html();
```

But I want to replace **all** `<a>` tags with the content of their `<span>` elements.

Please notice that there can be more than 3 links in my string and they can look different (different `<span>` and `href` content).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) method:

```
$('.marked.user-link').replaceWith(function() {
    return $(this).find('span').text();
});
```

Comment: and there you go - a cleaner way :)

Comment: var text = $(this).closest('.post').find('.content').html();

        $('.marked.user-link').replaceWith(function() {
            return $(this).find('span').text();
        }); 
How can I use it in the string now ??

Answer (score 0):

@clark, that makes complete sense. I haven't go the time to code it up now but if the structure is always 1  per  then you could create an array of all  tags and then cycle through them, replacing them with the first indexOf

will try to find time to run up an example later if that's not sufficient. Tough there might well be a cleaner way.

Comment: would be great, if you can give me an example